# Django rest - router is not creating url path, giving 404, and the api webpage has incorrect urls listed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

ive created some urls with the default router as per the below:

api.urls

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework_bulk.routes import BulkRouter
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
#### NEW ####
router.register(r'data/credentials/', views.DataCredentials)
router.register(r'data/site_circuits', views.DataSiteCircuits)
router.register(r'data/subnets/', views.SubnetsSet)
router.register(r'data/device_conns/', views.DataDeviceConns)
router.register(r'data/email_subscriber/', views.DataEmailSubscriber)
router.register(r'data/pd_user/', views.DataOnCall)
router.register(r'data/bgp/', views.DataBGP)
router.register(r'data/device/routingtable/', views.DataDeviceRoutingTable)
router.register(r'monitoring/bgp/', views.MonitoringBGP)
router.register(r'monitoring/script_results/', views.MonitoringScriptResults)
router.register(r'monitoring/circuit_maintenance/', views.MonitoringCircuitMaintenance)
router.register(r'monitoring/device/routingtable/', views.MonitoringDeviceRoutingTable)
#### LEGACY ####
router.register(r'credentials', views.CredentialDataROView)
router.register(r'tasks', views.TaskSet)
router.register(r'subnets', views.SubnetsSet)
router.register(r'device_conns', views.DeviceConnViewSet)
router.register(r'script_results', views.ScriptResultsView)
router.register(r'circuit_maintenance', views.CircuitMaintenanceView)
router.register(r'email_subscriber', views.EmailSubscriberROView)
router.register(r'pd_user', views.OnCallROView)
router.register(r'bgp_monitoring_data', views.BGPMonitoringDataView)
router.register(r'bgp_status', views.BGPStatusView)
router.register(r'rt_get_devices', views.MonitoringRoutingTableGetDevice)
router.register(r'rt_get_tables', views.MonitoringRoutingTableGet)
router.register(r'rt_upload', views.MonitoringRoutingTableUpload)
router.register(r'contact_type', views.ContactTypeROView)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    #### NEW ####
    path('data/site_subnets/', views.DataSiteSubnets.as_view()),
    path('data/site_circuits_subnets/', views.DataSiteCircuitSubnets.as_view()),
    path('data/device/routing_table/', views.DataDeviceRoutingTable.as_view({'get': 'list','put': 'update'})),
    path('data/geomapping/', views.DataGeoMapping.as_view()),
    path('monitoring/oncall/', views.MonitoringOnCall.as_view()),
    path('monitoring/site_connectivity/', views.MonitoringSiteConnectivity.as_view()),

    #### LEGACY ####
    path('ss_monitoring_data/', views.SiteSupernetMontioringDataROView.as_view()),
    path('monitoring/routing_data', views.MontioringGetRoutingData.as_view()),
    path('conn_set_single/<int:site_id>/<int:circuit_id>/', views.MonitoringConnectivitySetSingle.as_view()),
    path('conn_set/', views.MonitoringConnectivitySet.as_view()),
    path('site_circuits_pending/<int:days>/', views.SiteCircuitsPendingDataROView.as_view({'get': 'list'})), 
    path('upcoming_circuit_maintenance/<int:days>/', views.UpcomingCircuitMaintenanceView.as_view({'get': 'list'})), 
    path('aws_bgpdata_set/', views.MonitoringBGPDataSet.as_view()),
    path('aws_dc_set/', views.MonitoringAWSDirectConnectSet.as_view()),
    path('aws_vpn_set/', views.MonitoringAWSVPNSet.as_view()),
    path('four_g_set/', views.FourGDataSet.as_view()),
    path('contact_set/', views.ContactSet.as_view()),
    path('site_contact_set/', views.SiteContactSet.as_view()),
    path('device_version_set/', views.DeviceVersionSet.as_view()),

]
```

home.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
....
```

and then I attempt to hit the URL http://localhost:8100/api/data/device/routingtable/ and I am greeted with a 404, would anyone know why this is?

and when I hit my api home page and it lists urls, they are mapped to the wrong views:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    ...
    "data/device/routingtable/": "http://localhost:8100/api/rt_upload/",
    ...
}
```

views.py:

```
class DataDeviceRoutingTable(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=2)
    queryset = DeviceData.objects.all().select_related('device','device_use').order_by('monitoring_order')
    serializer_class = SerializerDataRoutingTable
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)   
    filter_class = DeviceData
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('device__hostname','device_use__use')
```

serialisers.py:

```
class SerializerDataRoutingTable(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hostname = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='device.hostname', )
    site_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='device.site_id', )
    routing_table = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='routing_table',)
    use = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='device_use.use', )

    def get_routing_table(self, instance):
        try:
            return json.loads(instance.routing_table)
        except:
            return instance.routing_table

    class Meta:
        model = DeviceData
        fields = ('id','site_id','device_id','hostname','use', 'timestamp', 'routing_table')   
        depth = 1
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib import admin

import app_settings.views
admin.autodiscover()

handler400 = 'app_settings.views.bad_request'
handler403 = 'app_settings.views.permission_denied'
handler404 = 'app_settings.views.page_not_found'
handler500 = 'app_settings.views.server_error'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
```

Comment: Did you add router's urls to urlpatterns list?

Comment: yeah its in there, some of the urls work, some of them dont and some point to the wrong views

Comment: Can you show url.py file?

Comment: hi ive added that now, thanks

Comment: Could you also add `api.urls.py` and `home.urls`? Probably there is some url in home.urls aor api.urls clashed with viewset url.

Comment: ive added that too

Comment: Do you use BulkRouter or DefaultRouter? If it's Bulk do you use BulkModelViewSet?

Comment: default by the looks

Comment: In import you have this line `from rest_framework_bulk.routes import BulkRouter`. So it's not using? I don't see any other problems.

Comment: so ive removed all the urls from the page except that one and it now works, im going to start putting them in one by one to see which one breaks it

Comment: Did you encounter the problem when reading? @AlexW